# I can't seem to access automatically named objects (instance##) placed on the stage in AS3, am I missing something?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have a movieclip in the library that is added to the stage dynamically in the document class's actionscript. This movieclip contains many many child images that were imported directly from photoshop at their original positions (which *must* be preserved).

I do not want to manually name every single image instance, as there are dozens upon dozens.

I have already gone through and manually converted the images to symbols, as apparently flash won't recognize the "bitmap" objects as children of a parent movieclip in AS3 (numChildren doesn't see the bitmaps, but it sees the symbols).

I have an array filled with references to the dozens of children, and I loop through it, checking if each one is under the mouse when clicked. However, somehow, it is not detecting when I click over the items **unless I manually name the child symbols** (I tested by manually naming a few of them -- those ones became click-sensitive.)

I have already done `trace()` debugging all throughout the code, verifying that my array is full of data, that the data is, in fact, the names of the instances (automatically named, IE instance45, instance46, instance47, etc.), verifying that the function is running on click, verifying that the code works properly if I manually name the symbols.

Can any one see what's going wrong, or what aspect of flash I am failing to understand?

Here is the code:

```
    //check each animal to see if it was clicked on
    private function check_animal_hits():void
    {


        var i:int = 0;
        var animal:Object = this.animal_container;

        for (i=0; i<animal.mussels.length; i++)
        {

            if (this.instance_under_cursor(animal.mussels[i].name))
            {

                var animal_data = new Object();
                animal_data.animal = "mussel";
                this.send_data(animal_data);

            }
        }


    }
```

Here is the code for the `instance_under_cursor()` method:

```
    // Used for finding out if a certain instance is underneath the cursor the instance name is a string 
    private function instance_under_cursor(instance_name)
    {
        var i:Number;
        var pt:Point = new Point(mouseX,mouseY);
        var objects:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(pt);
        var buttons:Array = new Array  ;
        var o:DisplayObject;
        var myMovieClip:MovieClip;


        // add items under mouseclick to an array
        for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        {
            o = objects[i];
            while (! o.parent is MovieClip)
            {
                o = o.parent;
            }
            myMovieClip = o.parent as MovieClip;

            buttons.push(myMovieClip.name);
        }


        if (buttons.indexOf(instance_name) >= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }



        return false;
    }
```

### Update:

I believe I have narrowed it down to a problem with [`getObjectsUnderPoint()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint%28%29) not detecting the objects unless they are named manually.

Comment: Have you considered using JSFL to automate the process of naming your objects?

Comment: I already manually named them because I am on a deadline. I'm more concerned with WHY this doesn't work, not how to find a workaround any more. Thank you though, I will look into that next time I have a repetitive task like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the most bizarre way to find objects under mouse pointer... There is a built-in function that does exactly that. But, that aside, you shouldn't probably rely on instance names as they are irrelevant / can be changed / kept solely for historical reasons. The code that makes use of this property is a subject to refactoring.

However, what you have observed might be this: when you put images on the scene in Flash CS, Flash will try to optimize it by reducing them all to a shape with a bitmap fill. Once you convert them to symbols, it won't be able to do it (as it assumes you want to use them later), but it will create Bitmpas instead - Bitmap is not an interactive object - i.e. it doesn't register mouse events - no point in adding it into what's returned from getObjectsUnderPoint(). Obviously, what you want to do, is to make them something interactive - like Sprite for example. Thus, your testing for parent being a MovieClip misses the point - as the parent needs not be MovieClip (could be Sprite or SimpleButton or Loader).

But, if you could explain what did you need the `instance_under_cursor` function for, there may be a better way to do what it was meant to do.

Comment: What built in function are you talking about? I'm using this function because I have layers upon layers of movieclips and images on the stage, there are many instances in which the user can't even see the object their mouse is over, because it's under 3 other objects, however I still need to know if they are above it.

Comment: Is there any way I could rewrite this function to not use names, and not require that I manually name the objects it is going to detect? I also already removed the check for parent being a movieclip thing, that was from an old application

Comment: I am comparing the names because I wasn't sure how else to compare the objects returned by getObjectsUnderPoint and the object(s) I am checking to see if the point is over.   I am using this instance_under_cursor function to detect whether or not the cursor, or certain movieclips, are over various irregular hitzones.

Comment: So I can just do `buttons.push(myMovieClip);` instead of `buttons.push(myMovieClip.name);` and change `instance_name` to just `instance` and feed in an object reference instead of an object's name?